# How to display multiple object data in html table in django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I passed two queryset objects from views to template both have product data with its features now the main problem is how to show this both objects data simultaneously in HTML table?

table structure:

```
features1 | product1 features value 1 | product2 feature value 1
features2 | product1 features value 2 | product2 feature value 2
...
```

```
<tbody>                              
     {% for a in product_data %}{% for b in product_data_2 %}
         <tr class="row" style="line-height: 3">
              {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                    {% for feature_data in a.product_features.all %}{% for feature_data_1 in b.product_features.all %}
                        <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4" style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">
                             {{ feature_data.feature.feature_name }}
                         </td>
                        <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4" style="text-align: center;">
                             {{ feature_data.product_feature_value }}               
                         </td>                
                         <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4" style="text-align: center;">
                             {{ feature_data_1.product_feature_value }}
                         </td>
                    {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
              {% elif forloop.counter < forloop.parentloop.counter  %}
                    something
              {% elif forloop.parentloop.counter < forloop.counter  %}
                    something
              {% endif %}
          </tr>
     {% endfor %}{% endfor %}

 </tbody>
```

please try to answer i tried but nothing work

Comment: There are two probably much more simple ways: 1) build two separate tables ordered similarly and align them horizontally with css 2) prepare data in the view - build a single rowset with all the needed values ready for straightforward output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your purpose you can use access by [index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) and [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with first_obj=product_data.0 %}
{% with second_obj=product_data.1 %}
...
{% for feature_data in first_obj.product_features.all %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
{% for feature_data in second_obj.product_features.all %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this only shows 1 feature for both product I want multiple

Comment: @Sahilshaikh this shows multiple features for each of two products because you iterating over features in loop (without seeing your models I assume `product_features` is correct attribute).

Comment: yes now it gives all data but 1 problem please see question and tell me how to show data in table with given format!

Comment: You didn't provided enough details. Do all products have same feature set? If no, then how you want to deal with situation when feature are different (can't show the value for product that do not have a feature where another product do have). Perhaps you need to query features table to determine common for both products first.